# How to find memory usage of Kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, kaggle

I want to know how to find the memory usage of a Kaggle notebook. How can I find that how much RAM has been used while running a Kaggle notebook. Kaggle is a site which allows python jupyter notebooks to run on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to track your memory usage of the notebook:

```
import os, psutil  

def cpu_stats():
    pid = os.getpid()
    py = psutil.Process(pid)
    memory_use = py.memory_info()[0] / 2. ** 30
    return 'memory GB:' + str(np.round(memory_use, 2))
```